# band name for landsat surface reflectance product

Tags: landsat, band

I'm looking for any link/documentation where the centre wavelengths of Landsat surface reflectance product are  stated/written (i.e. the value for each centre band). Specifically, I wanted to be sure the band names are same as Landsat 8. All I've seen so far is the band 1, band 2, band 3..... naming convention without the exact value.

Answer (score 1):

This USGS page contains the wavelength range per band per sensor:
https://landsat.usgs.gov/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites

Answer (score 1):

As, @jbdcode says, you can find wavelenghts in [What are the band designations for the Landsat satellites?](https://landsat.usgs.gov/what-are-band-designations-landsat-satellites)

Also, check [LANDSAT 8 SURFACE REFLECTANCE CODE (LASRC) PRODUCT](https://landsat.usgs.gov/sites/default/files/documents/lasrc_product_guide.pdf) (available for Landsat 5 and 7 too). This product guide describes almost all the info that you need (range, valid range, fill value, scale factor, quality band, etc).

Finally, check `.xml` for each scene to be sure:

[image]